# Replace the year in pandas.datetime column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with a date column converted using pd.to_datetime(). When I inspected the data I found few of these dates with year mentioned as 2216, which should have been 2016. Can you please help me change the year for these dates from 2216 to 2016

```
     Date
0   2216-12-21
1   2216-12-23
2   2216-01-31
3   2016-12-23
4   2216-12-27
5   2216-12-25
6   2016-12-23
```

I tried using str.replace

```
 df['Date'] = df['Date'].str.replace("2216","2016")
```

but got the following error

```
 Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas
```

Thanks In advance

Comment: You can add what you try? Your code? Because it is reason for downvotes...

Comment: Thanks for pointing that @jezrael. I have edited the question. I was wondering what did I do wrong for all the down votes.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use:

```
df['Date'] = df['Date'].mask(df['Date'].dt.year == 2216, 
                             df['Date'] + pd.offsets.DateOffset(year=2016))
print (df)
        Date
0 2016-12-21
1 2016-12-23
2 2016-01-31
3 2016-12-23
4 2016-12-27
5 2016-12-25
6 2016-12-23
```

For better performance:

```
df['Date'] = df['Date'].mask(df['Date'].dt.year == 2216, df['Date'] - 
                                                         pd.to_timedelta(200, unit='y') + 
                                                         pd.to_timedelta(12, unit='h'))
print (df)
        Date
0 2016-12-21
1 2016-12-23
2 2016-01-31
3 2016-12-23
4 2016-12-27
5 2016-12-25
6 2016-12-23
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks!. But I am getting a performance warning while executing this "PerformanceWarning: Non-vectorized DateOffset being applied to Series or DatetimeIndex
  "or DatetimeIndex", PerformanceWarning)"

Comment: @Ram - Added faster solution.

Comment: The second method leads to an error, I think due to a change in Pandas: "ValueError: Units 'M', 'Y', and 'y' are no longer supported, as they do not represent unambiguous timedelta values durations."

Comment: @jezrael that is brilliant, thanks. However, how would the formula change so whatever the starting year (not just 2216) would need to be converted to 2006?

Comment: @Andreuccio - do you think `df['Date'] += pd.offsets.DateOffset(year=2016)` ?