# how to replace all years value by another?

Tags: python, pandas, python-datetime

for some reason I need to replace all my years values by another.
here is a reproducible example

```py
df=pd.date_range(start="1970-01-09",end="2020-10-30").to_pydatetime().tolist()
df=pd.DataFrame(df,columns=['dte'])
df["dte_"]=df["dte"]+pd.offsets.DateOffset(year=2000)
```

This works but I get this warning :

```
C:\Users\E31\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arrays\datetimes.py:702: PerformanceWarning: Non-vectorized DateOffset being applied to Series or DatetimeIndex
  warnings.warn(
```

I checked on internet, I saw this solution [Replace the year in pandas.datetime column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50674011/replace-the-year-in-pandas-datetime-column)
but it doesn't work for my case.
If someone can help me, thanks !

EDIT :
I have also tried

```py
df["dte_"]=df["dte"]+pd.DateOffset(year=2000)
```

But I still have the warning.

Comment: I tried and I still have this warning, I'll edit my post

Comment: `for some reason I need to replace all my years values by another. here is a reproducible example` makes little sense to me, what area you trying to do?

Comment: for a graph I need to have all my dates with the same year. I have data from 1970 to 2020, and to represent them correctly I want to have each date with the same year, it already works nicely, except this warning

Comment: `df['dte'].apply(lambda x: x + pd.offsets.DateOffset(year=2000))`

Comment: so you want all the years to be in the year 2000 ?

Comment: thanks @Matt ! it seems it has worked !

Comment: @Matt The following code gives me correct ouput `df["dte_"]=df["dte"]+pd.offsets.DateOffset(years=1)` but not `df["dte_"]=df["dte"]+pd.offsets.DateOffset(years=2000)`. Can you please explain why?

Comment: @Umar.H That won't work because it doesn't take account of the fact that 1970 wasn't a leap year but 2000 was, etc. You will probably end up with dates of 29 February in years that didn't have one.

Comment: @BoarGules of course, that makes sense. Then you'll need to use a lambda - I wonder if the dateoffset also offsets the date if its a leap year.

Answer (score 1):

```
df=pd.date_range(start="2020-10-09",end="2020-10-30").to_pydatetime().tolist()
df=pd.DataFrame(df,columns=['dte'])
df["dte_"]=df["dte"]+pd.offsets.DateOffset(year=242)
```

The above code gives me the error you caught, i  replaced year to years which avoids the error

```
df["dte_"]=df["dte"]+pd.offsets.DateOffset(years=2000)
```

But pandas pd.offsets.DateOffset was limited to 241 accroding to the output i got

```
df["dte_"]=df["dte"]+pd.offsets.DateOffset(years=241)
```

And i applied the answer from Mr.Matt which gives correct solution

```
df["dte_"]=df['dte'].apply(lambda x: x + pd.offsets.DateOffset(year=2000))
```

> Somebody can tell is there truly limitation in pandas? Because i cannot find any documenation from pandas

Here is my code

```
df=pd.date_range(start="2020-10-29",end="2020-10-30").to_pydatetime().tolist()
df=pd.DataFrame(df,columns=['dte'])
df["dte_"]=df["dte"]+pd.offsets.DateOffset(years=241)
```

Output

```
dte dte_
0   2020-10-29  2261-10-29
1   2020-10-30  2261-10-30

df["dte_"]=df["dte"]+pd.offsets.DateOffset(years=242)
```

Output

```
dte dte_
0   2020-10-29  1678-04-09 00:25:26.290448384
1   2020-10-30  1678-04-10 00:25:26.290448384
```

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to replace all the date:**

1. Replace year 2019 with the year you want in the final result

---

```
df=pd.date_range(start="1970-01-09",end="2020-10-30").to_pydatetime().tolist()

df=pd.DataFrame(df,columns=['dte'])

dataFrameVar = df['dte_']

dataFrameVar.replace(year = 2019)
```

Comment: sorry, I'm not sure to understand what you are doing. I tried and I got an error ```File "C:\Users\E31\Documents\cours\stage_dossier\projet_python\tool_etiage\test.py", line 15, in <module>
    dataFrameVar.replace(year = 2019)
TypeError: replace() got an unexpected keyword argument 'year'```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Matt for the answer :

```py
df = pd.date_range(start="1970-01-09",
            end="2020-10-30").to_pydatetime().tolist()
   

df=pd.DataFrame(df,columns=['dte'])

df["dte_"]=df['dte'].apply(lambda x: x + pd.offsets.DateOffset(year=2000))
```